# Can we have a graphing tool for Physics.SE?

Tags: feature-request

> ### Post linked with [this MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179167/can-we-have-a-graphing-tool-for-math-se-and-physics-se) post

Graphing tool is very important for answering and asking some questions in Physics.
Graphing tool must include the function plotting and **drawing some free shapes.**

> This post is for further discussion on this and getting the comments and suggestions on this of Physics.SE users especially. As CrisF ♦  asked to post that on Site Meta. .

Comment: I suspect there would be more and more interesting discussion if you could identify come candidate tools. I mean, in principle this would be really nice, but we already have the pig MathJax running along with markdown, so the question becomes how much of a burden are you proposing and what do we get?

Comment: In addition to what dmckee wrote, you should add some examples of posts that would benefit from such a thing.

Comment: I would be happy to see a graphing tool, but I'm unsure that it can be simple yet broad enough that I wouldn't do it in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Could we use Wolfram Alpha as a widget embedded in answers? is that legal?

In order to avoid multiple hits of the Wolfram website, an image cache would be generated and stored on the SO server, and updated upon edit

Answer (score 2):

As regards free-body diagrams and the like, I think users will be better off with a client-based simulator as the range of possible requirements is probably too broad for a web-based tool.

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23676/8563) has good links to physics simulators. I have used Algodoo and it seems to work well (plus, it's free).